# Python True/False for the following code

Tags: python, boolean

How is evaluated the Python code:

```
not not True or False and not True
```

As of myself, I have two guesses:

**Method 1:**

> Step  Code
>   *1*        not not True or False and not True
>   *2*        not **False** or False and **False**
>   *3*        **True** or False and False
>   *4*        **True** and False
>   *5*        **False**

**Method 2:**

> Step  Code
>   *1*        not not True or False and not True
>   *2*        not **False** or False and **False**
>   *3*        **True** or **False**
>   *4*        **True**

Comment: What do you mean "which of the following method is correct"?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I mean what is the correct outcome for this: not not True or False and not True

Comment: You need to go through [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: You dont have to solve anything, pytohn does it for you. Is this question about the order of evaluation?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! I want to know the order of evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the table of [Python's operators precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

- `or` has lower precedence than
- `and` which in its turn has lower precedence
- than `not`

---

According to that:

```
  not not True or False and not True
```

Is the equivalent to

```
  ((not (not True)) or (False and (not True)))
```

---

EDIT: As noticed by Martijn Pieters in a comment below, worth mentionning that Python has short-circuits operators. That means that `and` and `or` are guaranteed to be evaluated left-to-right *and* that:

- If the left-term of an `or` is `True` the right term is never evaluated (as the result of `True or whatever` is `True` in boolean logic)
- If the left-term of an `and` is `False` the right term is never evaluated (as the result of `False and whatever` is `False` in boolean logic)

So, given your example:

1. The first step is to evaluate `not True` to `False`:

   ```
    ((not (not True)) or (False and (not True)))
           ^^^^^^^^
            False
   ```
2. Then `not False` is evaluated to `True`:

   ```
    ((not    False  ) or (False and (not True)))
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          True
   ```
3. As we no have `True or ...` Python stops evaluation immediately with the result `True`:

   ```
    (     True        or (False and (not True)))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ......................
                     True         (right-hand side ignored)
   ```

Comment: Then it should be True at last? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BlueFishy: it'll be True as `or` short-circuits if the first expression is True. What comes to the right of `or` is then simply ignored, never executed.

Comment: @Martijn Thank you for your comment. I've edited my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

To understand that, you should see the [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Your code is equivalent to:

```
((not (not True)) or (False and (not True)))
```

Now you should be able to tell what answer is correct and why.